# List to Dictionary - multiple values to key

Tags: python-2.7, csv, dictionary

I am very new to coding and seeking guidance on below...

I have a csv output currently like this:

```
'Age, First Name, Last Name, Mark'  
'21, John, Smith, 68'  
'16, Alex, Jones, 52'  
'42, Michael, Carpenter, 92 '
```

How do I create a dictionary that will end up looking like this:

```
dictionary = {('age' : 'First Name', 'Mark'), ('21' : 'John', '68'), etc}
```

I would like the first value to be the key - and only want two other values, and I'm having difficulty finding ways to approach this.

So far I've got

```
data = open('test.csv', 'r').read().split('\n')
```

I've tried to split each part into a string

```
for row in data:  
     x = row.split(',')
```

EDIT:

Thank you for those who have gave some input into solving my problem.

So after using

```
myDic = {}
for row in data:
    tmpLst = row.split(",")
    key = tmpLst[0]
    value = (tmpLst[1], tmpLst[-1])
    myDic[key] = value
```

my data came out as

```
['Age', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Mark']
['21', 'John', 'Smith', '68']
['16', 'Alex', 'Jones', '52']
['42', 'Michael', 'Carpenter', '92']
```

But get an IndexError: list index out of range at the line

```
value = (tmpLst[1], tmpLst[-1])
```

even though I can see that it should be within the range of the index.

Does anyone know why this error is coming up or what needs to be changed?

Comment: Is that actually what the file looks like? That's not CSV... there are single quotes and square brackets that I wouldn't expect in a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an actual valid CSV file that looks like this:

```
Age,First Name,Last Name,Mark
21,John,Smith,68
16,Alex,Jones,52
42,Michael,Carpenter,92
```

the following code should do what you want:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

    d = { row[0]: (row[1], row[3]) for row in reader }

print(d)

# Output:
# {'Age': ('First Name', 'Mark'), '16': ('Alex', '52'), '21': ('John', '68'), '42': ('Michael', '92')}
```

If `d = { row[0]: (row[1], row[3]) for row in reader }` is confusing, consider this alternative:

```
d = {}
for row in reader:
    d[row[0]] = (row[1], row[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want output like this:

dictionary = {'age' : ('First Name', 'Mark')}
Then you can use the following code:

```
myDic = {}
for row in data:
    tmpLst = row.split(",")
    key = tmpLst[0]
    value = (tmpLst[1], tmpLst[-1])
    myDic[key] = value
```